# Two coaxial cones have different voltages, therefore an electric field is in between them. Why does the voltage potential only depend on $\theta$

Tags: electromagnetism

Sorry if this is a dumb question but in the material I've read, it says that $V$, or the voltage potential, only depends on $\theta$. An example of this is [here](https://www.uotechnology.edu.iq/dep-eee/lectures/2nd/Electromagnetic%20fields/Part2_e.pdf) in Example 6.4

As you go higher up the cone, the distance between the surface increases so shouldn't $V$ be dependent on the radius $r$?

I am no means questioning the material, I just want some kind of a visualization of how it works so I understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry is scale invariant - that is, sending $r\rightarrow\lambda r$ leaves the geometry unchanged. It's also $\phi$-invariant. So the potential can only depend on $\theta$.